# Different Footer To Different Languages In Wordpress, forminator, polylang

Tags: wordpress, footer, custom-wordpress-pages, polylang

I developed my website using WordPress without coding...
I used the Astra template and made it multilingual using the Polylang plugin
The problem is in the footer of the site. I have a form, which I created using forminator

I created a 2 forms for each language
I did not find a way to display each form in its own language

How do I solve the problem?

I've seen some people say that from appearance and then customize
I can create two widgets and make each one appear in a specific language, but I do not see this option [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfWcw.png)